# Adding & Deleting Field sets on the fly in php - jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I was trying to add a 'set of fields' on to a page and also delete some of the 'on-the-fly' created set-of-fields from the page. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pegawega/t3k2vf9c/)
I am able to add a set-of-fields on to the page, but cant delete it, as the dynamically created  delete button is not firing `jquery event`.

I also want to disable the first delete button, as that row set is to be cloned all the time.

look at my code at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pegawega/t3k2vf9c/) and kindly correct the mistake I am doing.

Thanks for your time for looking at my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
            $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#live-alert").hide();
        //$("._remove_btn").hide();
$(".row").find('.btn_remove').attr("disabled", true);
        var maxEntries=5;
        var counter=1;

        $("#extra").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            if(counter<maxEntries){
                $(".row:first-child").clone().removeAttr('id').appendTo("#set-group").find('.btn_remove').removeAttr("disabled");   
                $(".row").find('.btn_remove').removeAttr("disabled");

                counter++;
            }           
            else
            {
                alert("only 5 rows can be added");
            }
        });

        $("body").on('click','._remove_btn',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("remove div clicked"+counter.toString());
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            counter--;
            if ($(".row").length == 1) {
                $('body').find(".row").find('.btn_remove').attr("disabled", true);
            }

        });     
    });
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t3k2vf9c/3/